# Absolute path in Razor for window.open() function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, url, razor

I would like to call from javascript

```
window.open("< full URL to my '/controller/action/id' >", "My test page")
```

in Razor, but I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Action` method on the `UrlHelper`.

You can access the `UrlHelper` in your view with the `Url` property:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open("@(Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id= 1}))", "My test page")
</script>
```